# max_num_pages returning number of posts instead of number of pages

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I am using the PBD Load Next Post plugin and it's working great, but I can't figure out why the max_num_pages is returning 44 (number of posts in that category) instead of 4 (number of pages it should be). Here are all the codes that should be relevant:

http://pastebin.com/ezAbD2eH

Here is the page that it is running on: garthreckers(dot)com/category/united-states/ (sorry, not enough rep to post another full link)

It's also running on the Europe page but its returning 20 over there (number of posts again).

Also, the if(mobile...) is from the mooble plugin if that makes a difference. I have tried stripping out the code for that and deactivating and it still doesnt work.

Any help will be great since I have been trying to fix this problem for 3 days now with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this may not be the best way but if you want to you can change the default number in the javascript as a workaround

Your JS http://pastebin.com/ezAbD2eH

Line 58:

```
var max = parseInt(pbd_alp.maxPages);
```

Change to:

```
var max = parseInt(pbd_alp.maxPages/12);  //divide it by the number of posts per page.
```

if you want you can probably set that as a variable and use it elsewhere where your $arg is as well so that the number is set globally.  Set $posts_per_page = 12 inside your PHP section.

```
var max = parseInt(pbd_alp.maxPages/<?php echo $posts_per_page; ?>);
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that in the php of the plugin file but it cuts off the last few posts since they aren't a full page. My backup in case nothing else worked was going to add 11 and then divide 12. Hard to put into words but my basic thinking is that if there is 1 post on the last page, the php will think it has a full page. If there are more than one, the overflow will just be phantom posts. Hopefully it works.

Comment: So far, the way I just said works, but I don't like the idea of hard coding the number of posts in the plugin. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I may have found your issue.  Currently in your PHP code when displaying all your posts you have a query that calls for Categories

```
wp_list_categories('show_option_none=&orderby=name&show_count=1&hide_empty=1&use_desc_for_title=1&child_of='.$cat.'&title_li=');
```

Currently this is throwing off the number as it is showing max_num_pages based on the category list number.  I would change the way you are displaying posts so that it is not using wp_list_categories to retrieve them.

Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

```
<?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 3 );
$lastposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach($lastposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: As far as the $count_pages goes, I tried adding it but it doesn't return anything. Tried an echo on the page and also tried it instead of $max = $wp_query->max_num_pages;. If this is wrong let me know but what seems like the problem is that something is keeping the post_per_page from being read. If that was the case then it would make sense why the max_num_pages isn't dividing by posts_per_page. I may be way off but thats my assumption.

Comment: Sorry about being unclear on the mobile question. It wasn't a question as much as it was mentioning why (is_mobile()) was in there since it isn't valid code. Thanks for mentioning the wp_is_mobile though. Didn't know they added that and I was able to get rid of a plugin.

Comment: I updated the answer for you.  After installing the plugin on my test server I have found the issue to be with the type of query you are using.  The plugin seems to be working just fine.

Comment: the wp_list_categories is actually for a list of sub categories below the title. I have tried taking it out and it doesnt seem to be affecting the number of pages. I replaced my query (the one contained in the <div class="gallery" id="content"> with the one you suggested and still no change. You are right about it showing the category list number instead of max pages.

Comment: Does it still do it if you remove all WP_query? and set it up as the blog static page on a standard template?  Can you provide updated code?

Comment: I commented out all the code I was previously using but here it is: http://pastebin.com/Wdpfxman

Comment: Removed them all. Nothing changed except now all the pictures show up (still displaying 44 even though there are more pictures on the page than that now.) Thanks for the help so far though.

Comment: You can probably put that 'cat'=>$cat back in there and I'll post a possible workaround for you.